# Can Spark-sql work without a hive installation?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have installed spark 2.4.0 on a clean ubuntu instance. Spark dataframes work fine but when I try to use spark.sql against a dataframe such as in the example below,i am getting an error "Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime."

```
spark.read.json("/data/flight-data/json/2015-summary.json")
.createOrReplaceTempView("some_sql_view")
```

spark.sql("""SELECT DEST_COUNTRY_NAME, sum(count)
FROM some_sql_view GROUP BY DEST_COUNTRY_NAME
""").where("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME like 'S%'").where("sum(count) > 10").count()

Most of the fixes that I have see in relation to this error refer to environments where hive is installed. Is hive required if I want to use sql statements against dataframes in spark or am i missing something else?

To follow up with my fix. The problem in my case was that Java 11 was the default on my system. As soon as I set Java 8 as the default metastore_db started working.

Comment: You should remove .createorReplaceTempView as it kind of create a temptable and would be using hive. apart from this you could query the DataFrame itself

Comment: So can you show me what those statements become without the use of .createOrReplaceTempView?

Comment: val df = spark.read.json ("json_datafile")      df.select("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME")    similar to this

Comment: Thats a dataframe query, not a SQL query. So it is not possible to run the sql query without using createOrReplaceTempView first. My question is, should I be able to run spark sql queries with the default spark install without also installing hive

Comment: I think you mean can instead of should.

Comment: Can you paste the entire stacktrace with `Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.` part?

Comment: [its a bit long so here is a link](https://www.scribd.com/document/395896473/Failed-to-Access-Metastore)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we can run spark sql queries on spark without installing hive, by default hive uses mapred as an execution engine, we can configure hive to use spark or tez as an execution engine to execute our queries much faster. Hive on spark hive uses hive metastore to run hive queries. At the same time, sql queries can be executed through spark. If spark is used to execute simple sql queries or not connected with hive metastore server, its uses embedded derby database and a new folder with name **metastore_db** will be created under the user home folder who executes the query.

Comment: For some reason that metastore_db is not getting created. I have tried passing -conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir but nothing gets created. Permissions are right on the folder

Comment: I find the answer confusing. ,by default ... is not relevant. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#run-sql-on-files-directly. Yes, 1.6. You can query files directly, Jdbc... They need not be in Hive.